# Why can't I save a payment processor in events

Tags: payment

When I choose paypal for an event - which is set up and has been used successfully for other events - it will not save
when I choose save and done I get this error
DB Constraint Violation - price_field_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for PriceFieldValue,get API. If so, please raise a bug report.

Comment: I just updated to civi 4.7.25 and was able to add payment processor to an event.